# Laravel Socialite first and last name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm adding social authentication to an application using Laravel's Socialite. I can retrieve the full name but not the first and last names separately. After the callback happens and Socialite is handling it, the user is retrieved successfully. If I am to dump the user I get back from `$user = this->social->driver('facebook')->user();` I get the following:

```
object(Laravel\Socialite\Two\User)#459 (8) {
     ["token" ]=> string(209) "{token}"
     ["id"] => string(17) "{socialID}"
     ["nickname"] => NULL
     ["name"] => string(14) "{Full Name}"
     ["email"] => string(19) "{Email address}"
     ["avatar"] => string(69) "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{socialID}/picture?type=normal"
     ["user"] => array(6) {
        ["first_name"] => string(6) "{First name}"
        ["last_name"] => string(7) "{Last mame}"
        ["email"] => string(19) "{Email address}"
        ["gender"] => string(4) "male"
        ["verified"] => bool(true)
        ["id"] => string(17) "{socialID}"
    }
    ["avatar_original"] => string(68) "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{socialID}/picture?width=1920"
```

}

I can obtain the full name or email via `$user->name` or `$user->email` however, I can not get the separate first and last names. I have tried `$user->first_name` as well as trying to dump the `$user->user` array but all I see is undefined property errors.

I do not want to do something weird like extract it from the full name when the separate first and last name are clearly there as it can get ugly when middle names are present.

I have Googled my way around and weirdly, nobody came across this issue. Am I missing something from [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication)?
Any suggestions on how to retrieve the first and last name from the `user` array are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$user->user['first_name']` should do the trick

Comment: @koala_dev For some magic reason, the user array was just another undefined property until now. This is silly :) Please add this as an answer so I can mark it as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the dump of the `$user` var you should be able to access the name values by doing:

`$user->user['first_name']` and `$user->user['last_name']`

Comment: Note, that the name parts are different with every provider, so with Google eg it's `$user->user['name']['givenName']` and `$user->user['name']['familyName']`.

Comment: Since different providers provide the first and last name values in different ways, isn't there a consisten way of getting the first and last name as separated values with Socialite? Something like `$user->getFirstname` and `$user->getLastname`.

Comment: Use offsetExists method to check if value exists, because if not you will get an error

Answer (score 18):

I've found that sometimes the user object won't contain the first and last names unless you specify you need those fields.

```
//get the driver and set desired fields
$driver = Socialite::driver('facebook')
                ->fields([
                    'name', 
                    'first_name', 
                    'last_name', 
                    'email', 
                    'gender', 
                    'verified'
                ]);
// retrieve the user
$user = $driver->user();
```

then you can get the first name and last name like this

```
$user->user['first_name'] and $user->user['last_name']
```

Other stuff you can ask for:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

for google plus:

```
$user->firstname = $user->user['name']['givenName'];
$user->lastname = $user->user['name']['familyName'];
```

Comment: This doesn't work with linkedin :/ Do you have any Idea ?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `offsetGet()` method which is defined in `AbstractUser` class of `socialite` package, which returns `$this->user[$offset];` so using it you can get first name and last name,

but for **facebook** and **google** it differs because of their different response so i have given code below for both facebook and google.

### For GOOGLE & FACEBOOK

```
$providerUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->user(); // $provider can be facebook, google etc.

switch($provider){
   case 'facebook':
      $first_name = $providerUser->offsetGet('first_name');
      $last_name = $providerUser->offsetGet('last_name');
      break;

   case 'google':
      $first_name = $providerUser->offsetGet('given_name');
      $last_name = $providerUser->offsetGet('family_name');
      break;

 // You can also add more provider option e.g. linkedin, twitter etc.

   default:
      $first_name = $providerUser->getName();
      $last_name = $providerUser->getName();
}

$user = User::create([
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'image' => $providerUser->getAvatar(),
            ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

In linkedin you can get first and last name from provider like this.

```
$linkedinUser = $this->socialite->driver('linkedin')->user());

$attributes = [
        'first_name' => $linkedinUser->user['firstName'],
        'last_name' => $linkedinUser->user['lastName'],
        'email' => $linkedinUser->email,
        'avatar' => $linkedinUser->avatar,
        'linkedin_id' => $linkedinUser->id
    ];
```

Comment: Also In google you can get first name as 'givenName' and lastname as 'familyName' in in user object.

Answer (score 1):

After coming against the same issue myself, i noticed that all social networks i used for registration/login (Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Github) send back a "**name**" attribute. This attribute can either be empty (if the user hasn't added any information) or carry a value.

What i did, was to create a method (getFirstLastNames()) that will get that "**name**" value and break it into **first_name** and **last_name** by exploding them when a space or multiple spaces is detected. Then i use them to populate my users table:

```
protected function getFirstLastNames($fullName)
{
    $parts = array_values(array_filter(explode(" ", $fullName)));

    $size = count($parts);

    if(empty($parts)){
        $result['first_name']   = NULL;
        $result['last_name']    = NULL;
    }

    if(!empty($parts) && $size == 1){
        $result['first_name']   = $parts[0];
        $result['last_name']    = NULL;
    }

    if(!empty($parts) && $size >= 2){
        $result['first_name']   = $parts[0];
        $result['last_name']    = $parts[1];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The $fullName variable is:

```
Socialite::driver($provider)->getName();
```

For this implementation i assume that:

1. No matter how many names the user has, i will use the first part of the string as the **first_name** and the second one as the **last_name**. [if my name is POPPY PETAL EMMA ELIZABETH DEVERAUX, then i will use POPPY as first_name and PETAL as last_name. The rest will be ignored]. If the "**name**" attribute comes back empty or with one name, then i insert NULL into the users table where i get no value.
2. If the user has used multiple spaces while separating the names (or before and after the names), this method will remove them and keep only the strings.

Now that you have the data in the array you can use them while creating the user:

```
$userFirstLastName = $this->getFirstLastNames(Socialite::driver($provider)->getName());

$user = User::create([
            'email'         => Socialite::driver($provider)->getName()->getEmail(),
            'first_name'    => $userFirstLastName['first_name'],
            'last_name'     => $userFirstLastName['last_name'],
        ]);
```

ps1: Make sure you change the migrations for users table (Laravel 5.3 uses only "**name**" field. If you need to have the "**first_name**" and "**last_name**" you should change it. Of course run "php artisan migrate:refresh" to implement the changes. All data will be lost.

ps2: Make sure the **first_name**, **last_name** and **password** fields can be nullable. Otherwise you will get an error.

ps3: Inside User model, add **first_name** and **last_name** and remove **name** in the $fillable property.

ps4: [Not Playstation 4] The **first_name** and **last_name** values can be altered by the user within your web app, if the above procedure used your second name as **first_name** or **last_name**. You can't predict what each user uses as a full name, so you need to make assumptions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should read this: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0):

And  you could simply do:

```
$NameArray = explode(' ',$user->getName());
$First_name = $NameArray[0];
$Last_name = $NameArray[1];
```

Comment: This does not deal well with names that consist of more than one word, which is not uncommon in last names, but can even be the case in first names (e.g. Gabriel José de la Concordia García Márquez).