# How can I get first name and last name from Facebook using Laravel Socialite?

Tags: laravel-socialite

How can I get first name and last name from Facebook using Laravel Socialite? By default I'm getting full name in a single field.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields(['first_name', 'last_name'])->user();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get field from provider like this.

```
//get the driver and set desired fields
$driver = Socialite::driver('facebook')
->fields(['name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'verified']);

// retrieve the user
$user = $driver->user();
```

follow this link for more details

[Laravel Socialite first and last name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407604/laravel-socialite-first-and-last-name/47054682#47054682)